# Can the gradle artifactory plugin publish plain binary files instead of MavenPublication?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

I want to upload a binary file to a local artifactory instance. The binary file is not a maven artifact so I do not want to use the `maven-publish` plugin, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Pseudo-code:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactoryConfig.context
    publish {
        repository {
            // Credentials and context path
        }
        defaults {
            publications (someSimpleFilePublication)
        }
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to exist anything else than `IvyPublication` and `MavenPublication` as valid publications in Gradle by default. I tried creating my custom `Publication` like below, but that yielded a new error:

```
interface FilePublication extends Publication {
    PublicationArtifact artifact(Object source)
}
publishing {
    publications {
        filePub(FilePublication) {
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
Cannot create a FilePublication because this type is not known 
to this container. Known types are: MavenPublication
```

I've read both the [artifactory plugin docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) and the [maven plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) but am none the wiser.

Please don't suggest to make my binary a Maven entity - there are a couple of reasons why I don't want to.

**Clarification**

With "plain" binary file as opposed to "Maven artifact" I mean a file that does *not* have a POM file, does *not* have a Maven Group ID, Artifact or Version String. It's just a file with a file system path.

I know it's possible to upload Plain Binary Files to Artifactory because I've done so through a plain HTTP PUT command from command line using [the Artifactory API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem to publish it as an artifact with the appropriate information to be consumed by Maven/Gradle and other tools..? This would mean no one else can consume by tools which are widely spread ?

Comment: We're solving an internal problem. The artifact is not to be consumed "by widely spread tools", but by a single tool (browser) that merely does an HTTP GET call to get the binary from artifactory. This use case is tested through manual upload with CURL. My fallback plan is to code the upload in Bash, but I'd prefer it to be a gradle task to better integrate with the rest of our build process

Comment: Maybe there is a small misconception. As far as I know, you can publish arbitrary binary files, but you would still use `MavenPublication` or `IvyPublication`. The term *MavenPublication* or *Maven Artifact* does not say anythink about the content of the file, but about where it is published. And you have to decide where to publish it. If you don't specify where it should be published, you cannot publish it. Basically, if your *local artifactory instance* is a Maven repository, then you want to use `MavenPublication`.

Comment: `MavenPublication` requires me to specify Maven artifact meta data like Group ID and version. See clarificaiton in OP I made. I do not wan to specify this. The artifact I upload does not have it